# P-values for glmer mixed effects logistic regression in Python

Tags: logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models, p-value

I have a dataset for one year for all employees with individual-level data (e.g. age, gender, promotions, etc.). Each employee is in a team of a certain manager. I have some variables on the team- and manager-levels as well (e.g. manager's tenure, team diversity, etc.). I want to explain the termination of employees (binary: left the company or not). I am running a multilevel logistic regression, where employees are grouped by their managers, therefore they share the same team- and manager-level characteristics.

So, my model looks like:

Termination ~ Age + Time in company + Promotions + Manager tenure + Percent of employees who completed training", data, groups=data[Manager_ID]

Dataset example:

```
data = {'Employee': ['ID1', 'ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5','ID6','ID7', 'ID8'],
'Manager_ID': ['MID1', 'MID2','MID2','MID1','MID3','MID3','MID3', 'MID1'],
'Termination': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
'Age': ['35', '40','50','24','33','46','44', '31'],
'TimeinCompany': ['1', '3', '10', '20', '4', '0', '4', '9'],
'Promotions': ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
'Manager_Tenure': ['10', '5', '5', '10', '8', '8', '8', '10'],
'PercentCompletedTrainingTeam': ['40', '20', '20', '40', '49', '49', '49', '40']}

columns = ['Employee','Manager_ID','Age', 'TimeinCompany', 'Promotions', 'Manager_Tenure', 'AverageAgeTeam', 'PercentCompletedTrainingTeam']

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

I managed to run mixed effects logistic regression using lme4 package from R in Python.

```
importr('lme4') 

model1 = r.glmer(formula=Formula('Termination ~ Age + TimeinCompany + Promotions + Manager_Tenure + PercentCompletedTrainingTeam + (1 | Manager_ID)'),
                            data=data)
print(r.summary(model1))
```

I receive the following output for the full sample:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 54867.6
Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9075 -0.3502 -0.2172 -0.0929  3.9378 
Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Manager_ID (Intercept)        0.005033 0.07094 
 Residual                      0.072541 0.26933 
Number of obs: 211974, groups:  Manager_ID, 24316
Fixed effects:
                                Estimate    Std. Error  t value
(Intercept)                     0.14635573  0.00299341  48.893
Age                            -0.00112153  0.00008079 -13.882
TimeinCompany                  -0.00238352  0.00010314 -23.110
Promotions                     -0.01754085  0.00491545  -3.569
Manager_Tenure                 -0.00044373  0.00010834  -4.096
PercentCompletedTrainingTeam   -0.00014393  0.00002598  -5.540
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Age    TmnCmpny  Promotions Mngr_Tenure
Age         -0.817                            
TmnCmpny     0.370 -0.616                     
Promotions  -0.011 -0.009 -0.033              
Mngr_Tenure -0.279  0.013 -0.076    0.035       
PrcntCmpltT -0.309 -0.077 -0.021   -0.042      0.052
```

But, there are no p-values displayed. I read a lot that lme4 does not provide p-values for a number of reasons, however I have to have them for the work presentation.

I tried several possible solutions that I found, but none of them worked:

```
importr('lmerTest')

importr('afex')


print(r.anova(model1))
```

1. does not display any output

```
print(r.anova(model1, ddf="Kenward-Roger"))
```

2. only displays npar, Sum Sq, Mean Sq, F value

```
print(r.summary(model1, ddf="merModLmerTest"))
```

3. Provides the same output as with just summary

```
print(r.anova(model1, "merModLmerTest"))
```

4. only displays npar, Sum Sq, Mean Sq, F value

Any ideas on how to get p-values are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you are running a logistic regression, as you haven't specified `family = binomial()` anywhere in the function call. I don't have experience with running lme4 from Python, but I would expect that to be the same.

Comment: yes, it did not work when I wrote it like family = binomial() or family = binomial, or family = "binomial". Python did not recognize it as argument. It worked with family=r('binomial(link="logit")'. However, convergence errors poped up. Adding arguments: control=r('glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa")'), nAGQ=0 - seemed to solve the issue.